Is the Multiverse Also "Fine-Tuned"?
EDIT This answer is closed for being "opinion-based"... could someone help me understand what is opinion-based about this question?
The apparent fine-tuning (not optimization) of our universe for the possibility of conscious life derives from the speculation that the fundamental laws and constants of our universe could have been otherwise -- i.e. they are not necessary.  In other words, we can model hypothetical universes where some fundamental laws or constants are different or do not exist -- for example, a universe without the Strong Force to hold particles together to form atoms, or a universe in which the speed of light is twice as fast.
This has led some people to propose the multiverse model, which postulates a multiverse which generates an infinite set of universes, each with a slightly different set of fundamental laws and constants and thus because of survivorship bias, our universe seems fine-tuned for the possibility of conscious life.
Now, in order to actually solve the problem of apparent fine-tuning, the multiverse model must not itself be equally "improbable" as our universe, otherwise it leads to a "multiverses all the way down" regression that doesn't get us anywhere.  However, it seems that the multiverse must be governed by at least some fundamental laws, one or more of which cause it to generate universes.  Our universe does not (as far as we can tell) spontaneously generate other universes, so we could infer that this "Law of Universe Generation" could be otherwise in the multiverse, much like we could imagine the speed of light to be otherwise in our universe.
My question then, is: Given that the multiverse seems to be governed by laws that could be otherwise, does it follow that the multiverse is "fine-tuned" for generating universes in the same way that our universe is "fine-tuned" for occasionally evolving conscious life?  Or am I missing something?
I am not asking about ID, or simulation hypothesis, or brute facts, or necessary existence, or whether this universe can even be said to be fine-tuned at all.  I am specifically asking about the multiverse model/hypothesis.
This question (Does a multiverse actually get rid of fine tuning?) seems related, but is down-voted without much in the way of answers, so I am posting a similar question hoping for better discussion.

@MrTea Fine-tuning is a questionable speculation, multiverse is a questionable speculation. Why do think that asking about fine-tuning of the multiverse finds a legitimate answer?

"This has led to the multiverse model" ? Can you please provide a reference for that. A strictly non-philosophical reference, if there is any.

@mudskipper It has led some people to espouse that model, no?  I've clarified what I mean.

Yes, but which people mostly? Physicists? Or philosophers?

@Jo Wehler I dabble a bit in game design, in which laws of physics and constants for those laws are anything but set in stone.  I could be incorrectly projecting that onto the real world, but at any rate our laws and constants seem too "convenient" for me and the multiverse model seems like the most scientific hypothesis to answer for this, but then it seems the multiverse hypothesis has some holes in it too.  Just wondering if someone smarter than me can patch them

@mudskipper I could not tell you what fraction of each category subscribes to the multiverse theory without conducting a survey with a significant sample-size.  Some people do, including some scientists and some philosophers, and I wonder about it too, hence this question.  Are you perhaps suggesting this should go on the Physics Stack Exchange instead of here?

@KristianBerry: The obvious objection to that sort of model is, essentially, a higher-dimensional version of "there's no uniform distribution over the reals." We do have the option of appealing to a non-uniform distribution, but it is unclear how the multiverse would "choose" such a distribution, which would necessarily involve favoring some configurations over others. The more natural option is to say that the multiverse does not obey the Kolmogorov axioms, but then you're side-stepping the original fine-tuning argument.

Mr.Tea Great idea: To consider fine-tuning and multiverse a subject for game design. Please dont't take it personally and go ahead :-)

@Mr.Tea - Yes, with all due respect to you, I see the discussion of fine-tuning as and even greater disaster then ID. So, I would indeed refer it to the phyics stack exchange to at least let it get a more thorough beating. Anyway, I don't see any value in philosophical discussions in talking about the actual physical structure of the universe or in sort of telling the physicists what they should believe. By merely thinking about things we can not discover any new empirical facts -- especially not if we don't even take empirical facts as starting points...

@MisterMiyagi But even a forest implies there is a world with rules that governs how trees grow, no?

If we didn't live in a universe that was fine tuned for our sort of life, we wouldn't be here to be surprised that it is fine tuned for our sort of life. I think this is only surprising when you fail to consider the alternatives.

Fine tuning of our universe is an active aspect of both philosophic and theoretical physics thinking, and there are multiple philosophers and physicists who publish on these questions.  There is no reason to close this entirely legitimate question, other than that there are physicalists here who find the subject psychologically uncomfortable to consider, and want to prevent this from being a topic on this site.

A very short answer to your question is: No. A bit longer is that the standard Model presumes that its constants are free variables, and Quantum Theory treats physics as probabilistic all the way down, such that spontaneous local shifts in the values or structure of the Standard Model is actually a reasonable inference.  Local shift in the SM == spawning a new baby universe.  Hawking discussed this in https://www.amazon.com/Black-Holes-Universes-Other-Essays/dp/0553095234  It seems to be easy to get to multiverses from our physics, while it is difficult to get to a life-supporting universe.

Why is this opinion-based? There is no empirical evidence of a multiverse, and therefore conjecture about its nature is conjecture about an imagined thing. Debating about the properties of the multiverse is a lot like debating the properties of a unicorn.

Any system with any specific measurable value that could be imagined to be different is fine tuned if that difference would preclude life existing.
The multiverse would need measurable constants to be fine tuned.
So,an observable multiverse lacking in measurable constants would not qualify.  One with constants would fall under the same unfalsifiable imagination game so long as we don't understand why the constants exist.

Are the existence of the "right" laws themselves not also theoretically variable though?  We can imagine a universe without the Strong Force (or whatever fundamental forces underlie it), regardless of what physical constants are associated with it.

The point is that these are imaginary scenarios.  They are not limited by reality until we understand the reality.
